# Gnome terminal scrollbar - hover changes width & wraps text

Tags: gnome-terminal, scrollbar

I'm using Gnome Terminal (under KDE, but I'm not sure if that's important), and when I hover my mouse over the scrollbar, the scrollbar gets wider and causes the text to wrap. Here's a GIF:

[image: Gnome terminal - scrollbar hover causes text to wrap]

It's like the terminal is not leaving enough space for the expanded scrollbar, so the text area gets narrower when you hover over the scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

*Update:* I'm not sure this works consistently... it maybe works with top, as top dynamically redraws when the width changes, but doesn't seem to work if it's just text on the terminal.  Results vary.

### Workaround

I've found an odd workaround: Under Edit -> Preferences (Profile Preferences) -> Scrolling, if you disable "Show scrollbar", and then re-enable, it works! The scrollbar no longer causes the text to wrap.

[image: Scrollbar no longer causes text to wrap]

This seems to have fixed all instances of Gnome Terminal - though I'm guessing I'll have to do this again next time I reboot.

Comment: Strange indeed: at first your terminal used a scrollbar changing width as you start using it. I turn the scrollbar off, and now turned it on to try to reproduce your problem, but also for me, it was fixed.